# ajax output doesn't come back from action page

Tags: jquery, ajax, anchor

I just wanted to display the output in my div `result2`.. but the output stays up in action.php?me=1... what is that I'm doing wrong here.. url issues or what..
I'm getting the output but not in this page..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.pop').click(function(e){ 
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            success: function(data){
                      $(".result2").append(html);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
</script>
<body>

<a href="http://ex.com/free/action.php?me=1"  class="member" id="member" rel="example">click to launch</a>
<div id="result2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a dozen in advance...

Comment: result2 is an id of a div therefore you need to use #

Comment: yes i changed that, but it says "html not defined".. am just echoing some string in php..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use id selector and not class... `.` is class selector.. whereas `#` is id... your result2 is id of that div.. and you are mnaming your response as data.. but you are using html there...

try this

```
$("#result2").append(html);
```

here

```
success: function(data){
         $("#result2").append(data);
       // --^---here   //-----^^^^---here your response is as data and not html
}
```

Comment: it worked with this data,but if u have time could you tell me, this works with ajax response data(i.e) the link was got from another page.. got from action.php.. it doesn't seem to work.. if u have any idea?? @bipen

Comment: make sure you returned the rite response in action.php

Comment: this is what is echoeed from action page..                         echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'><a href='http://ex.net/free/action.php?me=".$me."' id='member' class='member' >".$name."</a></td></tr>"; works the same way as above.. but reached the action.php?me=1 page for displayin the output

Comment: my ajax output from firebug  <html><body>

<table><tr><th>Trainer Available</th></tr><tr><td style='width: 200px;'><a href='http://ex.net/free/action.php?me=1' id='member' class='member' >trainer1</a></td></tr><tr><td style='width: 200px;'><a href='http://ex.net/free/action.php?me=2' id='member' class='member' >trainer2</a></td></tr></table></body></html>

Comment: ya that is fine.. so what is the problem in this ??

Comment: it is working well, but shows the output in action?me=id page.. this is same as above link except that this is a ajax response from action page.. hope am clear now

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(".result2").append(html);` to `$("#result2").append(html);`, because it's a id, not a class

Comment: thanks for reply.. but no it didn't work.. i have give both id and class the same name... should i set cache false.. does it have any impact..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.pop').click(function(e){ 
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            success: function(data){
                      // result2 is id, and there is no html but data.
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
```